# issue which is related to vuex store + cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, vue.js, vuex

I am creating SPA and I have one issue which is related to vuex store and cookies(vue-cookies).
When user logs in, the vue executes code

```
this.$cookies.set('username', 'player1', '1h');
this.$store.commit('logIn');
```

store:

```
store: {
    username: window.$cookies.get('username') || null;
}
```

mutations:

```
logIn (state) {
  this.state.username = window.$cookies.get('username');
}
```

After that, user logs in successfully and username is stored in vuex store. There is one problem however, when cookies expire, vuex store doesn't remove username.
  Any suggestions on how to remove username automatically when cookies are expired?

Comment: Are you doing anything for authentication you could tie into? I've handled stuff like this before by implementing authentication and removing cookies/cached login data when the user becomes unauthenticated.  Example: user hits logout button, expire login cookie and remove `username` from the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the `username` in the store to `''` at some point when you detect a user is no longer logged in or authenticated.

*In regards to my comment, here's a little code to see.*

Are you doing anything for authentication you could tie into? I've handled stuff like this before by implementing authentication and removing cookies/cached login data when the user becomes unauthenticated.  In one of our projects we created an `auth.js` store module to handle authentication.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question about automatically removing something from the store after a set time though. But it should clear the stored value when the cookie expires or is removed. Haven't tested though.

## Main app / calling store module

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      auth
    }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})


<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: "app",
    mounted() {
        let username = 'player1';
        this.$store.dispatch("LOGIN", username);
      }
}
</script>
```

## store/auth.js module

```
const state = { 
    username: {},
    isautheticated: {}
}

const getters = {
    username: state => state.username,
    isautheticated: state => state.isautheticated,
}

const mutations = {
    SET_USERNAME: function(state, username){
        state.username = username;
    },
    SET_ISAUTHENTICATED: function(state, isautheticated){
        state.isautheticated = isautheticated;
    },
}

const actions = {
    LOGIN: ({commit, dispatch}, username) => {
        if (!window.$cookies.get('username')) {
            //not logged in, create cookie based on username

            //save username in store by committing a mutation
            commit(SET_USERNAME, username);
        } 
    },
    LOGOUT: ({commit, dispatch}) => {
        //remove cookie
        //window.$cookies.remove('username')

        //clear username
        commit(SET_USERNAME, '');
    },
    IS_AUTHENTICATED: ({commit, dispatch}) =>
    {
        //loop into your authentication module and clear the cookie if user becomes unauthenticated
        //added an arbitrary isautheticated value to the store for an example
        if(!state.isautheticated) {
            commit(SET_USERNAME, '');
        }
    }
}

export default {
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
    state
}
```

Having this logic in the store `LOGIN` action is probably overkill if you're not calling out to a service to authenticate or get user data.

Comment: Thanks for help but I am confused, can you explain me please how "IS_AUTHENTICATED" action is supposed to clear store?

Comment: It's calling the `SET_USERNAME` mutation and setting the stored username to empty string here: `commit(SET_USERNAME, '');`.  Does that answer your question?